# Sim800 sim card requirements

Tags: gsm

What kind of a sim card is required for sim800 module? I know it must be activated and must be valid. But about 2g, 3g or LTE...What kind of a sim card in overall should I use with this module?

Comment: the question is: whether it will work with 4G or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What kind of a sim card is required for sim800 module?

*The SIM interface complies with the GSM Phase 1 specification and the new GSM Phase 2+ specification for FAST 64 kbps SIM card. Both 1.8V and 3.0V SIM card 
are supported. The SIM interface is powered from an internal regulator in the module.*

For more details see [here](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/sim800h_hardware_design_v1.00.pdf) and [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-fona-mini-gsm-gprs-cellular-phone-module/obtaining-a-sim). And remember "Google is your friend".

Cheers!

Comment: so if I were to go to a store to look for a sim card for a project related to sim800, I would ask for a 1.8V or 3.0V sim that complies with GSM phase 1 or 2+ specification right?

Comment: oh only 2g sim...and micro sim won't work

Comment: Actually I think it works like this; the SIM card gives a set of numbers to identify the unit when connecting to the network. The SIM800 can only connect with GSM (2G) so the SIM card must be for a vendor (service provider) that supports that.

Comment: So what kind of a sim should I ask the seller for?

Comment: You are still missing some info to be able to answer that. What size is the SIM card holder? You will have to ask for a 2G (GSM) SIM with the right size. Check other restrictions such as security (PIN) etc in the SIM800 documentation. It is all a question of reading.

Comment: a doubt: will 3g sim work?

Comment: The SIM800 can only connect to a 2G (GSM) radio network. The SIM card is not specifically GSM, 3G etc. It is the radio network service provider that must support GSM. They may call the SIM card 3G but the radio network may be a combination of technologies for provide coverage. You will have to stress that you need 2G (GSM) coverage.

Comment: I wanted to know that a regular sim or a micro/nano sim is required for this module:http://www.ebay.in/itm/SIM800-Quad-Band-GSM-Module-with-SMA-Antenna-Better-than-SIM900A-or-SIM900-/301782413058?hash=item4643a22f02:g:8LsAAOSwwbdWMidW

Comment: The SIM card holder is under the shield; http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxMzQ4/z/4KYAAOSw5VFWMidx/$_58.JPG Looks like a mini? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscriber_identity_module